# Grinding start on cold mornings

Tags: noise, grinding

I have a 2014 Honda CRV.  On mornings with temps in the upper 40's and below it makes a grinding noise when first starting.  Doesn't do it again the rest of the day.  Doesn't matter if my cars outside or in a garage.  It's been doing this since my car was about a year old.  It doesn't do it with warmer temps.  Honda wants me to leave it overnight to see if it will do it.  With Fall here, I'm waiting for cooler temps for that.  I'm wondering what's up before my warranty expires soon? 
In another post someone mentioned a defective VTC actuator for Hondas up to 2013.  Is this the same problem?

Comment: Have you lifted the hood (bonnet) and listened for a rough location of the noise as you start the engine?  If so, you could take a photo of the engine and point to the area where the noise comes from.

Comment: Does the noise stop as soon as the engine starts?

Comment: Is the noise synchronous with engine rpm or vehicle speed?

Comment: Sounds similar to this question - [Grinding sound during cold start](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/6133/grinding-sound-during-cold-start?rq=1) (also a Honda).

Comment: I dont have someone else to listen while I start my car.  The grinding stops just seconds after starting the car.  I found issues with cold starts on another site. I'm am hoping if Hondas not addressing this issue that it's nothing to worry about... And as someone else mentioned there hasn't been a recall for this problem.

Comment: Shoot a video of the engine with the hood open while a friend starts the car for you. Upload it to Youtube and share the link here.

Comment: Thank you for the advice!  Not sure why this does this only in the winter..